# How to plot an ROC curve after 5-fold cross validation for multiclass classification problem?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How to add 5 fold cross-validation and plot ROC curve in the multiclass classifier.....

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from scipy import interp

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]

# Add noisy features to make the problem harder
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# shuffle and split training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.5,
                                                    random_state=0)

# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,random_state=random_state))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class


fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()


for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])


plt.figure()
lw = 2
plt.plot(fpr[2], tpr[2], color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[2])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()



all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))


mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)


for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])


mean_tpr /= n_classes

fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

# Plot all ROC curves
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})' ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]),color='deeppink', linestyle=':', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],label='macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})' ''.format(roc_auc["macro"]),color='navy', linestyle=':', linewidth=4)

colors = cycle(['aqua', 'darkorange', 'cornflowerblue'])

for i, color in zip(range(n_classes), colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], color=color, lw=lw,label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})' ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Some extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to plot curve each combination of folds in cv?

Comment: Each Combination? I just want to plot a curve after cross-validation .. a mean or an average curve?

Comment: It is not clear what do you need. Do you wish to replace the "train_test_split" function with "StratifiedKFold"/"KFold"? and then you ask how to show the AUC ROC results? If that is the case, the next question is whether you wish to 1) show the average AUC score (easily done with "cross_val_score") or 2) to plot 5 AUC curves for each class (the "combinations" that were mentioned by Venkatachalam). Please clarify your question so we can assist you better.